# How to match the brother of a certain XML element in ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, html-parsing

I played around with nokogiri in ruby and the XML searching feature, e.g.:

```
a = Nokogiri.XML(open 'a.xml')
x = a.search('//div[@class="foo"]').text
```

which works quite nice.

But how can I specify to match the next (brother) element on the same level (and only the next)?

For example for this input:

```
<div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div>EXTRACT ME</dev>
  ...
</div>
```

The actual input is some non-XHTML html, but so far Nokogiri.XML does not complain.

Btw, what filter syntax f.search actually expects? xpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the hint from Brian Agnew and DevNull I guess that f.search actually expects xpath syntax and using the following-sibling predicate the following expression matches what was asked:

```
a = x.search('//div[@class="foo"]/following-sibling::div[1]')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want XPath's [following-sibling](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example15.html) predicate.

Comment: @maxshlepzig - you'll also want to look at the predicate section in http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp to specify the first following-sibling.